# Duplicate error when renaming files using FORFILES in BATCH with a search mask

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running a batch script using FORFILES with the search mask `/M *.log.*` on files such as these:

```
a.log.1
a.log.2
a.log.3
```

I want to rename them by appending the current date and move them to the destination folder. But I get an error stating:

> Duplicate file names

Only the file `a.log.1` is moved to its destination and renamed.

This is my code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ( 'forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @path" /d -7 / m *.log.*' ) do ren "%%~G" "%%~nG-%Ret%"
```

Comment: For some reason asterisk is not getting printed :(

Comment: code looks something like this  for /f "delims=" %%G in (
'forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @path" /d -7 / m *.log.*'
) do ren "%%~G" "%%~nG-%Ret%"

Comment: You should edit your question rather than commenting when detailing your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that differentiates the three files is the extension (`.1`, `.2`, or `.3`). But your target name uses the base name only, without the extension, so of course you get duplicate names. You could change your target name to include the extension using `"%%~nxG-%Ret%"`. (I assume you have defined `Ret` elsewhere.)

But I don't see any need for your FOR loop - the FORFILES can do the rename directly:

```
forfiles /s /d -7 /m *.log.* /c "cmd /c ren @path @file0x22-%Ret%0x22"
```

I don't know what your date format in %Ret% looks like, so I included quotes (`0x22`) around it just to be safe. It looks weird, but a name like `"name.ext""date"` works just fine - the quotes are stripped out, but they protect against spaces and special characters.